# Error android.view.InflateException: in android log cat

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, exception

Am populating the values into ListView from json response.for that i have created one ArrayAdapter upon run the code its throwing the error as shown below.

```
08-08 19:06:39.939 28394-28394/com.inspirenetz.app.inpartner E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.inspirenetz.app.inpartner, PID: 28394
                                                                           android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class <unknown>
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
                                                                               at com.inspirenetz.app.inpartner.adapter.RedemptionRequestListViewAdapter.getView(RedemptionRequestListViewAdapter.java:35)
                                                                               at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2306)
                                                                               at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1263)
                                                                               at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1175)
                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16820)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5156)
                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16820)
                                                                               at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
                                                                               at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16820)
                                                                               at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
                                                                               at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16820)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5156)
                                                                               at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:610)
                                                                               at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:677)
                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16820)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:940)
                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16820)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5156)
                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16820)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5156)
                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16820)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5156)
                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16820)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5156)
                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16820)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5156)
                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2294)
                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16820)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1969)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1162)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1348)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1049)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5899)
                                                                            at android.view.Choreographer$Callb
```

here my adapter code

```
public class RedemptionRequestListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RedemptionRequestResource> {

private final Context context;
private List<RedemptionRequestResource> objects;

public RedemptionRequestListViewAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<RedemptionRequestResource> objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    this.context = context;
    this.objects = objects;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.redemption_request_listview, parent, false);

    TextView lblRedemptionDate =(TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.lblRedemptionDate);
    TextView lblTrackingId =(TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.lblTrackingId);
    TextView lblLoyaltyId =(TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.lblLoyaltyId);
    TextView lblRedemptionStatus =(TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.lblRedemptionStatus);

    RedemptionRequestResource redemptionRequestResource = objects.get(position);

    lblRedemptionDate.setText(redemptionRequestResource.getRdmDate());
    lblTrackingId.setText(redemptionRequestResource.getRdmUniqueBatchTrackingId());
    lblLoyaltyId.setText(redemptionRequestResource.getRdmLoyaltyId());
    lblRedemptionStatus.setText(redemptionRequestResource.getRdmStatus());

    return rowView;
}
}
```

here my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/customersearch_bg"
    tools:context="com.inspirenetz.app.inpartner.redemption.RedemptionRequestListFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/lblRedemptionDate"
            android:text="Redemption Date"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            style="@style/EditTextDarkTheme"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/lblTrackingId"
            android:text="Tracking ID"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            style="@style/EditTextDarkTheme"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Loyalty ID :"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            style="@style/EditTextDarkTheme"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/lblLoyaltyId"
            android:text="Loyalty ID"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            style="@style/EditTextDarkTheme"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Status :"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            style="@style/EditTextDarkTheme"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/lblRedemptionStatus"
            android:text="Status"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            style="@style/EditTextDarkTheme"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

the error denoting in this line of array adapter

```
 View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.redemption_request_listview, parent, false);
```

can anyone please help me on this.

Comment: Your error lies in the XML file you're inflating. Please post the `redemption_request_listview` XML file.

Comment: Post your `redemption_request_listview` xml code. otherwise kindly check line no. 19 in this xml.

Comment: please see my xml file above

Comment: DO you have multiple dimens.xml files? if yes can you check whether dimens used in the layout file are present in each of the files. If no a possible issue could be in EditTextDarkTheme

Comment: yes after u removed EditTextDarkTheme its working now thanks @Smit Davda

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but I suspect your problem is in your .axml layout file. Can you show us this file?

Especially check line number 19, as your log says this is where the error happens.

Comment: please see my xml file above

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use: 
`LayoutInflater inflater=((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater()`

Comment: i have tried it throwing java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity error

Comment: Have you tried doing: LayoutInflater inflater= LayoutInflater.from(context) ?

Comment: again it throwing android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class <unknown> error

Comment: Clean your project, rebuild it and try compiling again.When you bring changes to Xml, IDE throws these sort of errors.